# REGEX: \s\d{3,4}\b\n\n?

Tags: regex

[version of regex - ICU via TextSoap 8 for the Mac by Unmarked Software]

In the example below I need to capture a line of text like this:

```
Today's XXXX ZZZZZZZ ###/#

Some paragraph of Txt......????
```

So the XXXX and ZZZZZZZ are words, and the #### are numbers. Note that there are two lines there, one a new line after the "todays..." line and then a blank line. And then a paragraph of text. It's actually the paragraph of text that I am interested in. I want to set up my REGEX to do 2 things. One is to capture the digits, which is what it's doing now....perfectly. The second thing is to capture the text afterwards to justify the text. However, I can't figure out what I have to do it to get to the last \n where the "???" are in the text above.

Any suggestions ?

Here's an example string....

https://regex101.com/r/cN3kZ7/3

Comment: What you describe is not what you show. You're showing "Today's ....", then no blank line, then paragraph text. So, what do you really need to match? Any line that starts with "Today's" and ends with "number number number slash number"? As for suggestions: debuggex.com and rege101.com are your best friend, you should be able to find the answer all on your own with them.

Comment: What's the point in not providing real life input strings???

Comment: You should just use your perfect regex and then match (.*) behind it for the rest.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, thanks.

Comment: @Jan, the point is because the text of XXX and ZZZZ is a variable. As is #### value. That's why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like the following?

```
(?:^Today)\D*(?<numbers>\d+)(?:.*\R){2}(?<text>.*)
# look for Today at the beginning of the string/line in multiline mode
# match any non-digits
# capture numbers into the group "numbers"
# match .*\R two times - this is two lines including the newline character
# capture the text into the group "text"
```

See [a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/aB0fU9/1). Obviously, you could as well leave the number and text part (and use `$1` and `$2` accordingly):

```
(?:^Today)\D*(\d+)(?:.*\R){2}(.*)
```

This will capture the text into the group `$2`.
If you want **all** the text (including other lines), you'd need some inline modifiers (`(?s)` and `(?s-)` in this case), a lazy quantifier and a stop word:

```
(?:^Today)\D*(\d+)(?:.*\R){2}(?s)(.*?(?=stop))(?s-)
# the same as above
# turn on single-line mode (?s) - the dot matches newline characters as well
# capture everything lazily (!) until 
# the positive lookahead finds "stop" literally
# turn off the single line mode afterwards - (?s-)
```

See an example for [this approach here](https://regex101.com/r/aB0fU9/3).

**EDIT:** In the end we used the following regex (see comments below):

```
^\h+\D+(\d+)(?:.*\R){2}(.+)
```

Comment: So to be clear, (?:^Today)\D*(\d+)(?:.*\R){2}(?s)(.*?(?=stop))(?s-) will grab everything UNTIL it hits the word "STOP" ? That's great. However, each paragraph doesn't have a stop, except maybe a \r or \n. So would the stop in this case be (?:^Today)\D*(\d+)(?:.*\R){2}(?s)(.*?(?=\n))(?s-) ????

Comment: @MagicMiles: [No](https://regex101.com/r/aB0fU9/4) - provide some real life input strings (edit your original question) and let's see if we can find a solution.

Comment: Additionally, this one stops before **stop**  or at an empty line: https://regex101.com/r/aB0fU9/5

Comment: @MagicMiles: Glad to be of any help :-) Updated the answer (see the bottom).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just need to enable a multi-line tag.

```
/\s\d{3,4}\b\n.*\?{3}/gm
```

[Regexer example](http://regexr.com/3co9o). You'll probably want to put capture groups around the decimals and text, like so:

```
/\s(\d{3,4})\b\n(.*)\?{3}/gm
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like `^Today\'s\s.+\s(\d+)\/(\d).*\n(.*)`